# setting environment variables in jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a jenkins build script for my project in Groovy.
the problem is that I want to define some variables at the top of the script and use them when I want as Environment variable.

```
def someVariable = 'foo'

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("build"){
            environment {
                specialParameter = someVariable
            }
            steps{
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

I have some other steps that their environment variables are different and also I want to just change the top of the script to able to build other branches and so on. so I just want a way to use the defined **someVariable** in the **environment** body.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can just use the environment section to define environment variables which are known in you whole script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        TEST='myvalue'
    }
    stages{
        stage("build"){
            steps{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also define a variable which is only known in one stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("build"){
            environment {
                TEST='myvalue'
            }
            steps{
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But for your solution (using def above the pipeline) you can just do:

```
def someVariable = 'foo'

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("build"){
            steps{
                echo someVariable
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will output `'foo'`.

You can get more informations on [variable declarations syntax by reading Jenkins online book.](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline)

UPDATE:

```
def someVariable = 'foo'

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("build"){
            environment {
                TEST = sh(script: "echo -n ${someVariable}", returnStdout: true)
            }
            steps{
                sh 'echo "${TEST}"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ echo foo
foo
```

Comment: maybe my question is ambiguous, I think you did not pay enough attention to my question, last sentence of my question specifies what I want. I want to use declared variable inside "environment body" not in "steps", just look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just found another way to use defined environment variables.

```
def getsomeVariable (){
    return 'foo'
}


pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("build"){
            environment {
                specialParameter = getsomeVariable()
            }
            steps{
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }

}
```